# replicate matlab interp3 in python, interpolate to unevenly spaced matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation

I need to replicate a specific case of MATLAB's `interp3` functioning that I cannot replicate using scipy.

I have the first 3D space defined as `x`, `y`, `z` (meshgrids or vectors), and values `p`. I need to interpolate those values in a new 3D space defined as `x_new`, `y`, `z`. For context `x`, `x_new`, `y`, and `z` are 4999x84x83 matrices.

The problem is that `x_new` changes in all its directions, so it cannot be considered a regular meshgrid or a vector.

The line I need to replicate is the following:

```matlab
fn = interp3(y, x, z, p, y, x_new, z, 'linear');
```

In Python I tried to implement it using scipy as:

```py
points = (x,y,z)
values = p
xi = (x_new,y,z)

fn = scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan)
```

Or using `griddata` as:

```py
fn = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x,y,z), p, (x_new,y,z), method='linear', fill_value=0, rescale=False)
```

But both methods give rise to errors due to the non-even spacing of the `x_new` matrix.

Is there a method to replicate the `interp3` function in Python? I can give you access to data if you want to try this problem first-hand.

Comment: when you use `interp3`, only the first 3 values (the ones that define the space) are required to be a regular grid, the rest are just single combinations of (x,y,z) points. This is the same in python, simply input 1D arrays there, you can reshape later.

Comment: thank you Ander, you are right but my problem is that I'm not able to define x_new as a vector, given that it changes in all the 3 directions. In Matlab, I can input directly the matrix. Scipy requires vectors as you said, but I'm not able to represent x_new as a vector. Does this explain more my situation?

Comment: of course you can define it as a vector, you just unroll it. in matlab, `x_new(:)`, in numpy `x_new.ravel()`

Comment: thank again Ander, with your help I made it work. Do you know of any possibility to speed up the interpolation or using GPU for this task?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Ander comment now it works just like Matlab. Like this:

```
points = np.c_[(np.ravel(x_new), np.ravel(y), np.ravel(z))]

X, Y, Z = np.shape(p)

x_vect=x[:,0]
y_vect=y[:,0]
z_vect=z[:,0]

Vi = interpn((x_vect,y_vect,z_vect), p, points,bounds_error=False,fill_value=0, method='nearest')

Vi = np.reshape(Vi, (X, Y, Z))
```